# python protobuf assign a dictionary to any fields of google proto

Tags: python, python-3.x, proto, protobuf-3

I have a.prot file which consists of below fields
user.proto

```
message Integration {
 string db_name = 1;
 oneof payload {
        Asset asset = 2;
        }
     }
message Asset {
 string address = 1;
 google.protobuf.Any extra_fields = 2;
 }
```

I just want to assign a large dictionary to extra_fields like below

importing the generated pb2 file

```
import user_pb2
i = user_pb2.Integration()
i.db_name = "sdsdsd"
i.asset.address = "sdsd"
i.asset.extra_fields = {"assd":"sdsd","sd":"asd"...}
```

but it is raising the

```
AttributeError: Assignment not allowed to field "extra_fields" in the protocol message object.
```

I don't want to specify the filed names in proto because my dict contains over 100 fields I just want to assign total dict to extra fields
can anyone suggest how to insert dict to extra fields?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to skip `.asset` and assign `i.address` or `i.extra_fields` directly. For example:

```
i.extra_fields = {"a": "b"}
```

see the documentation: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#oneof

Comment: it is not taking direct value @acrazing

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we figured out how to add the dict to protobuf directly,
using struct keyword in google protobuf

```
message Integration {
 string db_name = 1;
 oneof payload {
        Asset asset = 2;
        }
     }
message Asset {
 string address = 1;
google.protobuf.Struct extra_fields = 2;

 }
```

instead of any we used struct
in the assigning, we can do directly update the dict

```
import user_pb2
i = user_pb2.Integration()
i.db_name = "sdsdsd"
i.asset.address = "sdsd"
i.asset.extra_fields.update({"assd":"sdsd","sd":"asd"})
```